# Linq to Entities: usage of function causes multiple queries

Tags: linq-to-entities, user-defined-functions

I noticed very strange Linq to Entities behavior if user defined functions (which are properly declared and connected to Linq) are used in Linq query.
Suppose I execute statement

```
var list = (from ts in context.Tests select MyFunction(ts.TestId));
```

Linq builds correct SQL Select query, which uses MyFunction properly. But the problem is: Linq generates and sends this statement for every row in the table instead of sending it once! I looked in SQL profiler and found that the number of times this Select statement is sent to server is exactly the number of records in Test table…

What is this? Is it another bug in Linq to Entities? Does anybody know any workaround? As behavior like this really makes database side functions not usable.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is resolved. It turned out that SQL Profiler was wrongly reporting multiple statements. The Linq actually sends only 1 statement.

Answer (score 0):

But this is precisely what you have written in your LINQ query: select a result of MyFunction(ts.TestId) for every row in the Tests table. 
If you have 25 rows in your table than your resultset will contain 25 records as well, each obtained by executing MyFunction.

What do you actually want to do? Do you want to execute MyFunction only once? If so, which TestId you want to pass if you have 25 records?

Comment: Of course MyFunction() should be executed as many times as there are records in the table. This is not my concern. The problem is that SQL statement itself (select MyFunction(TestId) from Test) IS SENT to SQL server 25 times! If you look in SQL profiler and check what is going on behind the execution of this statement you will understand what I am talking about.

Comment: @Dimitry - Obviously I don't have neither your code nor your database so I cannot just 'look in SQL profiler'. It may help if you post more code, especially one that evaluates your linq query.

Comment: You do not need my database or my code to look at this very generic problem. Just create any user defined function, connect it with Linq to Entities and run any Linq query, which is using this function. Now look at SQL profiler and you will see that it deals with abnormally big number of queries (instead of just 1 query, which is expected).